# How to build a dynamic hierarchy in excel such as Power Pivot Drill-down report?

Tags: excel, treeview, hierarchy, powerpivot, drilldown

**Source Format:**

| Id | Department | EmployeeName | ManagerId | Salary |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Software Development | John | null | 150000 |
| 2 | Software Development | Vikram | 1 | 125000 |
| 3 | Software Development | Ram | 2 | 100000 |
| 4 | Software Development | Mathew | 3 | 75000 |
| 5 | Software Development | Priya | 1 | 120000 |
| 6 | Data Engineering | Tony | null | 145000 |

I have the above structure data. "ManagerId" references "Id". Employee and their levels are undefined, it will increase or decrease, because it is dynamic. I want to build the reported visual in Excel to drill down this hierarchy at the end.

Most of the blogs and articles they are showing column level hierarchy but I need it in the row level. I really appreciate it if I get a solution for this. Thanks in advance.

The hierarchy should be in the below format. If I get the format in the drill-down method that would be great.

[image: Expected Output]